# Underline TextView in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have this code in my adapter :

```
class CustomListView2 extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private Context context;
        int hasil;
        public CustomListView2(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_listview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.no_order = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no_order);
                holder.status_order = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_order);
                holder.tgl_antar = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tgl_antar);
                holder.check_order = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBatal);
                holder.layoutHistory = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutHistory);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

       if (mapStatus.containsKey(position))
        {
            holder.status_order.setPaintFlags(holder.status_order.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.status_order.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

And i declared this in global variable :

```
Map<Integer,String> mapStatus = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

What im tying is only to make a textview getting underlined based on position that i have put in HashMap.

But after im scrolling the listview, the other textview is getting underlined too.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your view holder is reusing your view.
Try to add a `else` conditional with an opposite operation that remove the underline:

```
holder.status_order.setPaintFlags(holder.status_order.getPaintFlags() & !Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Not sure if `&` is used like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use SpannableString:

```
String mystring= mapStatus.getValue().toString();
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(mystring);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mystring.length(), 0);
yourtextview.setText(content);
```